# AngularJS factory returning State object instead of JSON data from promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-promise

I have made two factory and calling first from second one, consuming second one factory  in controller but instead of getting data as JSON, I'm getting data as $$State.
I'm new to angularJS tried many ways but not able to solve, please help.

```
 app.factory('userDetails', ['APIService', '$q', function (APIService, $q) {
    getDetails: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var getFunc = function () {
            APIService.doGetCall('Masters/employee/username/tarun')
                .then(
                function (data)
                { 
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                },
                function (data, status, headers, config)
                { 
                    deferred.reject('There was an error creating object'); })
                    return deferred.promise;
                 }
        var a = getFunc();
        return a;

    }
}

 vm.user = userDetails.getDetails();
console.log("user",vm.user);
```

response is as per below snippet

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC4MF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `.then` function to get response there. Rather I'd say you don't need to create extra promise, its an `anti-pattern`. Where you could utilize the promise return by `doGetCall` method directly.

```
app.factory('userDetails', ['APIService', '$q', function(APIService, $q) {
  getDetails: function() {
    var getFunc = function() {
      return APIService.doGetCall('Masters/employee/username/tarun');
    }
    var a = getFunc();
    return a;
  }
}]);

vm.user = userDetails.getDetails().then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
    vm.user = response.data;
    console.log("user", vm.user);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error)
}).catch(exceptionHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

`userDetails.getDetails()` returns a promise, Hence you need to use [`.then(onsuccess, onRejected)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

```
userDetails.getDetails().then(function(data){
   vm.user = data;
   console.log("user",vm.user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the

```
return deferred.promise;
```

line inside the APIService.doGetCall function. It should be outside of it.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: it means the getDetails function should return a promise when it gets invoked - the promise should be **returned** first, then after the API call the promise can be **resolved**. The way the code was written, the promise is only getting **returned** if the API call fails.

Comment: take code and format it.. you will see, Its correct what OP have